# How to access controller variable without passing to Play html

Tags: scala, playframework

Is it possible to access Play Framework scala contoller variables wihout passing to scala.html template?

For example my controller code as below,

```
    def index = Action { request =>
    val orgId = '12132132'

    Ok(views.html.index(request))
    }
```

My index.scala.html as below,

```
    @(implicit request: RequestHeader)
      @main("Test") {

    I want to access controller "orgId" variable here wihtout passing here.

         }
```

Here is my main.scala.html,

```
    @(title: String)(content: Html)
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @content <!-- index.html placed here --> 
    </body> 
    <div>
        Here I have bootstrap side menu and I want to display controller variable here without passing to main.scala.html templete.
    </div>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: No, Basically I would have made my request  in controllers as an implicit and pass orgId as an argument, and if there are more number of fields then make a case class and pass the instance of that case class in it.

Comment: Hi, in my case it is not possible. I have main.scala.html and I have already passed index.scala.html as @content:html parameter. I want to access controller variable on bootstrap modal which is another <div> in my main.scala.html and I can't pass another case class as parameter to my main.scala.html.

Comment: can you please pase some more code for your index and main html files.

Comment: Impossible.. breaks MVC pattern, tight coupling..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it since it private for the function. No other function can access it (even not in the same class).
If you are using object as instance of the controller (instead of class) and you use value of the object itself then you can do it, but It HIGHLY NOT recommended.
e.g.

```scala
object MyController extends controller {
  val orgId = '12132132'
  def index = Action { request =>
    Ok(views.html.index(request))
  }
  ...
}
```

---

```
@(implicit request: RequestHeader)
  @main("Test") {

I want to access controller "@{MyController.orgId}" variable here without passing here.

}
```

If you need to pass some data that isn't depend on the request, meaning it can be value of the object, then it also may be outside the controller. So you can create an object that will hold those values, and access them.
Technically it the same as use the controller, but logically it better separation.

Comment: Agreed with your point.. As per new play release we can create class as controller and in my case also I have created as class for my controller not as object. So as it is not a   recommended solution I should have to think another solution. Thanks for your time.

Comment: what does the "val orgId" is?  where you get it from?  is it calculated as part of the request and depend on it or is it calculated otherwise ? More details about it will allow suggesting better solutions

Comment: yes it is part of my request. Once user click on login I am doing oAuth to external org and calling web service(using play WS) with token received. As part of WS response I was getting orgId and I want to display it on menu on main.scala.html without passing to it.